# Google Cloud How to get authorization?

Tags: python, gcloud

I need to get the Instance List of my Google cloud project. So i tried this:

```
requests.get('https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/clouddeployment-265711/zones/europe-west3-a/instances)
```

How do i get authorization in python?.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

How do i get my "OAuth 2 access token" for my Google Cloud Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [full documentation on Server to Server authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python) which also includes sample codes for every method supported.

In this [GCP Github code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/api-client/snippets.py), you can see multiple ways of authentication that you might choose from depending on your use-case.

For example with this code sample you can use a service account JSON key for authentication:

```
# [START auth_api_explicit]
def explicit(project):
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    import googleapiclient.discovery

    # Construct service account credentials using the service account key
    # file.
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'service_account.json')

    # Explicitly pass the credentials to the client library.
    storage_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = storage_client.buckets().list(project=project).execute()
    print(buckets)
# [END auth_api_explicit]
```

UPDATE:
If what you want is simply getting the Bearer token and storing it in a python variable to make a simple GET request:

```
import os

your_key = os.system('gcloud auth print-access-token')
```

so your_key will now have the Bearer token that you need to include in your request header

Otherwise, please read through [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) which explains how to authenticate as an end-user.

Comment: I'm sorry but i think you are a few levels higher than me. So i understand nothing. I need to get OAuth2 Authentication for my Get Request in Python.

Comment: updated my answer with a few more options you might be referring to. If this is not what you want then please edit your question with the exact use-case and what is not working for you. @DerPazi